# Pyinstaller: made an exe but not working. How to fix these errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I tried to use pyinstaller but it's not working.

Whatever i use

`pyinstaller myapp.py`
or

`pyinstaller --onefile myapp.py`

or even go to spec file excludes

`excludes = ['PyQt5','gtk','Tkinter','matplotlib','PySide','PyQt5' ]` ,

but the same problem happen. This is all the errors i got

Excluding imports

```
87757 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
87764 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
87765 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
87771 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
87772 INFO: Excluding import 'gtk'
87779 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
87786 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
87787 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
87794 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module IPython.lib.clipboard
87796 INFO: Excluding import 'matplotlib'
87803 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib._pylab_helpers from module IPython.core.pylabtools
87803 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.backend_bases from module IPython.core.pylabtools
87804 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.figure from module IPython.core.pylabtools
87804 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.pyplot from module IPython.core.pylabtools
87805 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib from module IPython.core.pylabtools
```

Sklearn hidden imports

```
91074 WARNING: Hidden import "sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_validation" not found!
91074 WARNING: Hidden import "sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_tools" not found!
91075 WARNING: Hidden import "sklearn.utils.lgamma" not found!
```

Symbol AttrValue is already exposed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 20, in walk_packages
  File "c:\users\nam\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\~-thon\__init__.py", line 165, in <module>
    tf_export(v1=['AttrValue'])(AttrValue)
  File "c:\users\nam\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\tf_export.py", line 334, in __call__
    self.set_attr(undecorated_func, api_names_attr, self._names)
  File "c:\users\nam\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\tf_export.py", line 346, in set_attr
    (func.__name__, getattr(func, api_names_attr)))  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.util.tf_export.SymbolAlreadyExposedError: Symbol AttrValue is already exposed as ().
```

Hidden import tensorflow api and keras (loop errors)

```
100169 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2" not found!
100170 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.resnet50" not found!
100173 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications" not found!
100221 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.cifar100" not found!
100222 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.estimator.experimental" not found!
100879 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet" not found!
100943 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.estimator" not found!
100943 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.densenet" not found!
101202 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2" not found!
101207 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.datasets.boston_housing" not found!
101208 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.backend" not found!
101209 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.callbacks" not found!
101210 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v2.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2" not found!
101222 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.layers" not found!
101224 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.applications.inception_v3" not found!
101227 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.utils" not found!
101421 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.models" not found!
101421 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.mixed_precision" not found!
101423 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.preprocessing" not found!
101519 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.estimator.inputs" not found!
101520 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.keras.mixed_precision.experimental" not found!
101521 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.inception_v3" not found!
101619 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v2.keras.layers.experimental" not found!
101620 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet" not found!
101625 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras" not found!
```

Hidden import not found

```
105669 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zmq.py' from 'c:\\users\\nam\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
109534 WARNING: Hidden import "_cffi_ext.c" not found!
109534 WARNING: Hidden import "Cannot" not found!
109535 WARNING: Hidden import "fatal" not found!
109536 WARNING: Hidden import "open" not found!
109537 WARNING: Hidden import "error" not found!
109538 WARNING: Hidden import "or" not found!
109539 WARNING: Hidden import "file:" not found!
109540 WARNING: Hidden import "such" not found!
109540 WARNING: Hidden import "file" not found!
109541 WARNING: Hidden import "C1083:" not found!
109655 WARNING: Hidden import "directory" not found!
109656 WARNING: Hidden import "'zmq.h':" not found!
109657 WARNING: Hidden import "c:\users\nam\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(268):" not found!
109658 WARNING: Hidden import "No" not found!
```

Excluding package and main

```
141318 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'c:\\users\\nam\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
141324 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
141332 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
141339 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
141339 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
141345 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
141351 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
141352 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'c:\\users\\nam\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
141358 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
141364 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
141364 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'c:\\users\\nam\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
141989 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'c:\\users\\nam\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
142213 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
142321 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
142329 INFO: Excluding import '__main__'
142335 INFO:   Removing import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
142336 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pygments.py' from 'c:\\users\\nam\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
```

I think it has something to do with my packages. When i use `virtualenv`, instead of having a empty `venv` i has all my packages in my `venv`.

Comment: Show errors and other relevant text properly formatted in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: Please do not post code or textual output as image links. They should be included in the post. Additionally your second image is not a valid link.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a new. I'm figuring out how to do that

Comment: please wait 5 min . I am getting the code run so i can copy. Sorry everyone

Comment: All edited guys

Comment: No one answer. Is my question that bad ?

Comment: @expertDicer did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @PolarBear10 nope. I haven't. But that's not important anymore. I fcking quit the job :>